# I need /etc/pulse/default.pa code

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, default

I recently edited some code in default.pa and now my pulseaudio won't start.
Can somebody give me the code for it?
Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You can always ask APT to reinstall the package with default configuration file:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask" install --reinstall pulseaudio
# answer Y
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that but I got the error: Command line option --reinstall is not understood in combination with the other options

Comment: See updated answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped to get my file back.